# Find an object based on substring value

Tags: javascript

```js
const usecases =  [
    { usecaseId: 'Bill Gates', id: 1, description: 'CEO & founder, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Mark Zuckerberg', id: 2, description: 'CEO, Facebook' },
    { usecaseId: 'Steve Jobs', id: 3, description: 'CEO & co-founder, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Satya Nadella', id: 4, description: 'CEO, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Elon Musk', id: 5, description: 'CEO, Tesla & SpaceX' },
    { usecaseId: 'Ginni Rometty', id: 6, description: 'CEO, IBM' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Bezos', id: 7, description: 'CEO, Amazon' },
    { usecaseId: 'Larry Page', id: 8, description: 'CEO, Google' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jack Dorsey', id: 9, description: 'CEO, Twitter' },
    { usecaseId: 'Meg Whitman', id: 10, description: 'CEO, HP' },
    { usecaseId: 'Tim Cook', id: 11, description: 'CEO, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Weiner', id: 12, description: 'CEO, LinkedIn' },
  ]
  
 const str = "Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg, Tim Cook, Jeff Bezos, Steve Jobs";
 
 const newArr = usecases.filter(usecaseObj => {
    if(str.indexOf(usecaseObj.usecaseId) != -1) {
      return usecaseObj
    }
 });
 console.log(newArr)
```

I need to optimize the piece of solution to filter out the object based on string values, maybe using some ES6 feature.

Comment: What is the question again?

Comment: May be you can try posting this question in code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if it's only for optimization

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const usecases =  [
    { usecaseId: 'Bill Gates', id: 1, description: 'CEO & founder, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Mark Zuckerberg', id: 2, description: 'CEO, Facebook' },
    { usecaseId: 'Steve Jobs', id: 3, description: 'CEO & co-founder, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Satya Nadella', id: 4, description: 'CEO, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Elon Musk', id: 5, description: 'CEO, Tesla & SpaceX' },
    { usecaseId: 'Ginni Rometty', id: 6, description: 'CEO, IBM' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Bezos', id: 7, description: 'CEO, Amazon' },
    { usecaseId: 'Larry Page', id: 8, description: 'CEO, Google' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jack Dorsey', id: 9, description: 'CEO, Twitter' },
    { usecaseId: 'Meg Whitman', id: 10, description: 'CEO, HP' },
    { usecaseId: 'Tim Cook', id: 11, description: 'CEO, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Weiner', id: 12, description: 'CEO, LinkedIn' },
  ]
  
 const str = "Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg, Tim Cook, Jeff Bezos, Steve Jobs";

const newArr = usecases.filter(usecaseObj => {
    return !!str.match(usecaseObj.usecaseId)
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: They are asking for an optimized solution. There is a split and array.find in each loop.

Comment: Yes you are right Added another solution to this

Comment: Why return !!str.match(usecaseObj.usecaseId) double exclamation? can't we use directly str.match(usecaseObj.usecaseId)

Comment: its a double check !! convert it to true or false